# How to pretty print a comma delimited file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, pretty-print

Below is my file. I am trying to maintain constant width between my output so that all pipe symbols are one below the other and it looks like table format. How can I achieve that? I also need to have the same format when I mail the output.

```
cat file.txt
name,score card,ID
Jack,Available,YES
Jen,NA,NO
Jerry,Available,YES
Padula,NA,YES
Mackenzi,NA,NO

sed 's/,/\t|\t/g' c.txt
name    |       score card      |       ID
Jack    |       Available       |       YES
Jen     |       NA      |       NO
Jerry   |       Available       |       YES
Padula  |       NA      |       YES
Mackenzi        |       NA      |       NO

==I want==
name      |       score card      |       ID
Jack      |       Available       |       YES
Jen       |       NA              |       NO
Jerry     |       Available       |       YES
Padula    |       NA              |       YES
Mackenzi  |       NA              |       NO
```

Comment: Do you know the needed column widths in advance? Or do you expect to determine the maximum width of the content for each column? The latter would require two passes with any tool.

Comment: Maximum width of content can do it as column here

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Don't ask 2 completely different questions in 1 question. You originally asked how to produce tabular output and you got answers. Accept one and move on. Now you've edited your question to add a sentence "I also need to have the same format when I mail the output". If you don't know how to send fixed width text in whatever email client you use then post a new question asking how to do that if you like but, again, that would be a completely different question with different tags, different target audience, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/,/,|,/g' file | column -t -s,
name      |  score card  |  ID
Jack      |  Available   |  YES
Jen       |  NA          |  NO
Jerry     |  Available   |  YES
Padula    |  NA          |  YES
Mackenzi  |  NA          |  NO
```

Comment: This is really neat because it doesn't depend upon the number of columns.

Comment: Hi Morton, The output seems to be what I am looking for in the shell command line but when i mail this output, column width's just as before not even. How can I get the same format in Mail?

Comment: Use a constant width font in your mail? That has nothing to do with the shell or your question though - create any tabular file by hand and try sending it by mail. Debug that. Now do that same thing for this output.

Answer (score -1):

If same thing if you want to archive with `awk`,

```
awk -F"," '{printf "%-10s%s%-10s%s%-10s\n", $1,OFS,$2,OFS,$3}' OFS="|" file.txt
```

Comment: While this awk does the deed on this very specific example, it wont if you feed it values longer than 10 characters.